# Django Rest Framework filtering results displayed by serializer in a Model.objects.all() query

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to query my entire user database but only add the user to the json response if the field account_type is "supplier", right now it is just adding every user to the json response

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    <omitted>
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    ...<omitted>
```

views.py

```
class getusers(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # Database model
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    # Serializer - this performs the actions on the queried database entry
    serializer_class = GetUsersSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class GetUsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model=UserProfile
        fields=['user','company','email','pk', 'account_type']
```

current JSON response

```
[
    {
        "user": 1,
        "company": "kyle att",
        "email": "<omitted>",
        "pk": 1,
        "account_type": "user"
    },
    {
        "user": 2,
        "company": "kyle google",
        "email": "<omitted>",
        "pk": 2,
        "account_type": "supplier"
    }
]
```

desired JSON response

```
[
    {
        "user": 2,
        "company": "kyle google",
        "email": "<omitted>",
        "pk": 2,
        "account_type": "supplier"
    }
]
```

Comment: Update  `getusers.queryset` with `UserProfile.objects.filter(account_type="supplier")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 'queryset' as below:

```
queryset = UserProfile.objects.filter(account_type='supplier')
```

Comment: Won't this give the error MultipleObjectsReturned?

Comment: @kbessemer no, we may got such error in case we use ".get()" (e.g. ```UserProfile.objects.get(account_type='supplier')```)